# Drag and drop text from a JLabel outside the java application onto a pdf form

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I was wondering if it was possible to drag the text from a JLabel, out of the java application onto a pdf form for example.

If it is possible, could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Not in the strict way Thomas. From ur answer it looks like a lot of work involving JNI and the robot class. Didn't want to take so much trouble. Instead I have a small copy button trailing each text field. The user will have to click that button to copy the text and then paste it onto the form.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy.What i woud do- Put **listener** onto JLabel, take text on event that you pick.Copy text from the JLabel value into **Clipboard**,

Now you have text that you can manipulate.

Drag effect.=Use (with combination of the previous listener) **JNativeHook** lib to get **GLOBAL EVENTS** of java application and outside.
Listen for dragging(Do on your own its easy) , on mouse release onto your pdf input text.

You might have  to simulate mouse click(right after release) to select  field (via **robot class**) to actualy SELECT THAT FIELD,so you can input text.

Input text part=Use robot class to insert string char by char.

This will work well.I dont have any other idea atm that woud be this easy to implement.
You can also (fool user) with **effect of floating** text etc if you put transparent window over the top and check mouse location on screen.